# gmtime is giving me some times localtime?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

I'm printing events in a multi-thread environment the console is a static mutex shared by all the threads.

The problem is randomly every hundred or thousand events the time I get is local time and not UTC.

I have seen this error just in Linux machines (build with g++) but not in Windows (build VC++). I have no clue where I could start, any idea?

```
void  Publish(std::string source, std::string topic, std::string msg) NOEXCEPT {
    console.lock();
    std::time_t now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::to_time_t(*localTime);

    char buf[50];
    strftime(buf, sizeof (buf), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00", gmtime(&now));

    cout << buf << " " << source << " " << topic << " " << msg << endl;
    cout.flush();
    console.unlock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct tm * gmtime (const time_t * timer);
```

Converts time_t to tm as UTC time. This call uses the value pointed by timer to fill a tm structure with the values that represent the corresponding time, expressed as a UTC time (i.e., the time at the GMT timezone).

This must be working correctly.
However, not sure about this:

```
 std::time_t now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::to_time_t(*localTime);
```

Is your *localtime giving the current time accurately under multithreaded situation? Is it a shared variable?
Instead could you use the following:

```
std::time_t now = time(0);
```

Comment: *localtime is the local time of the thread, and is a simulated time. This mean I can't take the time from an external clock. But this time is only access by a single thread